# android google maps just one country

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using google maps v2 application on my Android. I wonder if there is a way to just show the map of a specific country, say France.

#### What I have tried

I tried to use *LatLngBounds* and then calculate the new LatLngBounds but this is for preventing the camera to go out of the country and it is kind coast solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the current Google Maps API, there is no such feature.

LatLngBounds is the best bet as far as I know.

Comment: since i have to check the bounds with oncamerachange, it is really very coast. and you can't tell exactly when the user go out of the bounders, right?

Comment: Yeah. I guess  it's not a very good solution. But, I don't think you have any other option with Google Maps. You could check other map libraries.